# Check if table exists easiest way?

Tags: c#

I made a project. In every next version which i release i add more tables and columns. But, example someone will have version 1.00 and someone 1.05.
In my realease e.x 1.06 i want to include all my added tables from version 1.00 till 1.05. This who will have version 1.00 to add him e.x 5 new tables this who will have version 1.05 just only one table.

The code i found to check if table exists is this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand CheckNone = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * from information_schema.tables where table_name= inventory) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);
        con.Open();

        var result = (int)CheckNone.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result == 0)
        {

           //my code...
        }
            else
        }//my code...
```

My question is should i write this hole code for everytime i add a table? Is this right?

Comment: Put it in a method that takes the table name as an argument, in order to avoid writing it multiple times

Comment: But if you are serious about software development then I suggest you to rethink this architecture and/or provide some method to upgrade users database otherwise you will soon reach the level in which the maintenance will become a nightmare.

Comment: True! but what other option do i have?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using SQL Server Data Tools project to manage the database. You can create snapshots of the SSDT project at each version and use sqlpackage.exe to make the db changes.

Comment: And this who have ex version 1.00 and wants going to version 1.06. He will run 5 sqlpackages? one package for each version i making a change?

Comment: Are you saying users will have different versions of the app and will use them against different versions of the DB? E.g. user A has version 1.00, user B has version 1.06 and the DB is at version 1.04? Or is there at least a guarantee that the DB will be at the very latest version and you have to support the current and all previous app versions?

Comment: Also, is there an installer that upgrades the DB or is the DB upgrade built in to the app that runs at startup or some other time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage the multi versions of your application against the existence of the table, check tables against version with simple xml file.

Define Xml file which include tables and  the corresponding Version.

The Format of the xml file may be:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Tables>
        <Table Name="table1"  Version="1.0.0"/>
        <Table Name="table2"  Version="1.0.0"/>
        <Table Name="table3"  Version="1.5.0"/>
        <Table Name="table4"  Version="1.5.0"/>
        <Table Name="table5"  Version="1.6.0"/>
        <Table Name="table6"  Version="1.6.0"/>
    </Tables>
```

Create Class that manage the xml file.

The following method Search the xml file and return its version.

```
     public string GetVersion(string tableName)
            {
                XElement xelement = XElement.Load(_xmlFileName);
                var table = xelement.Elements("Table").FirstOrDefault(m => (string)m.Attribute("Name") == tableName);
                if (table != null)
                {
                    var version = (string)table.Attribute("Version");
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1}", tableName, version);
                    return version;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
```

Check the version of the table with the current Version of the application and return true/false.

Define method like:

```
 public bool IsTableExist(string tableName)
    {
      // get version of table and compare with your application version
      // return true/false based on comparison
    }
```